# Facebook Graph API does not verify appsecret_proof correctly

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a server application that receives a user access token from the client and generates an appsecret_proof. I would like to make a graph API call in order to verify that the received access token is valid:

```
curl \
  -F 'access_token=<my access token>' \
  -F 'appsecret_proof=<my appsecret_proof>' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/me
```

However, when I omit the appsecret_proof field the request is still verified. In both cases the response is:

```
{"success":true}
```

If I intentionally pass an invalid appsecre_proof it works as expected:

```
{"error":{"message":"Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100}}
```

I have made the neccessary changes in the Advanced settings:

[image]

According to the Facebook documentation: "When this is enabled, we will only allow API calls that either include appsecret_proof or are made from the same device the token was issued to."
"Once you've changed that setting, an attacker will not be able to use stolen access tokens without access to your app secret."

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you show the cURL request you are doing (omitting the access token obv.), the response you are getting doesn't match what you have in your answer. You should be getting the user object, not success:true

Comment: Specifically can you try `curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=XXX'`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried it and indeed it returned the user object. There must be something wrong with using '-F'. The problem is that those who do not possess the appsecret can still access the user object this way.

Comment: Are you sure the access token you are using belongs to the app you switched the setting for? Currently the behaviours you are explaining are for an application with app secret proof disabled. (You can try yourself with another app and use an invalid `appsecret_proof`)

Comment: I'm absolutely sure that the access token belongs to my app. I checked it with this:
`https://graph.facebook.com/app/?access_token=<my access token>`
Also, when I change the setting back to 'No' nothing changes, it is really as though the access token belongs to a differenct app.

Comment: File a bug at developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: It was my mistake. Here is the response they gave me: 
"This particular behaviour is by design for mobile clients. We don't require requests to use an appsecret_proof when the access token used was issued by one of our mobile SDKs.

The reason for this is because mobile client access tokens have a very low risk of theft. This allows you to use these access tokens directly from the mobile app, while requiring that an appsecret_proof be supplied with access tokens from the web OAuth flow."

Answer (score 2):

**appsecret_proof** is not same as the **APP SECRET KEY**.
Based on FB documentation, this is how it needs to be obtained:

- go to http://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output
- in the **message area**, put the **access token**
- in the **secret key**, put the APP **secret key**
- Choose **SHA256** as the **digest algorithm**
- Generate the **HMAC**

You can use this generated HMAC as the my **appsecret_proof** in (for example):-

```
curl \
-F 'access_token=<my access token>' \
-F 'appsecret_proof=<my appsecret_proof>' \
-F 'batch=[{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"me"},{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"me/friends"}]'
https://graph.facebook.com/me
```

Omitting the appsecret_proof field might help but in certain regions, FB API demands for it and this is how you need to provide it